# Can I specify tighter security group controls in EC2?

Tags: security, juju

I see juju creates a new security group when we do a bootstrap, but this security group is so open that it allows all the machine inside the group to access all the ports.

Is it possible to create a restricted security group or is there an option/parameter in environment.yaml file to specify that?

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do it

This can be solved by creating a security group earlier ( with whatever security policy we wish), so that juju can use the same security instead of creating one.
Security group name should match the name that we specify in the environment.yaml file. For example , if we use the name "amazon", then the security group name should be "juju-amazon".

As zookeeper service ( bootstrap instance) is listening on the port 2181 for all the client request , we need to open 2181 port for the group.